# How to manually use springs default object mapper / manually deserializing of Http-Request Body to Object

Tags: spring-boot, jackson, spring-restcontroller, localdate

I have an generic Rest-Constroller which needs to construct an entity out of an entity-name an request body representing the entities properties.
I need to manually map the request body to an target class.

I already tried different ways to customize the way my RestController deserializes the data and think my current approach is the easiest.
I now register an @PostMapping and retrieve the entityName which i use to determine the correct class and an @RequestBody String entityJson which i convert via an ObjectMapper to the determined class.

yet i encounter problems during LocalDate deserialiing (Note: my date strings are of format 'yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ' where times are zeros).

I use springboot 2.1.6.RELEASE with jpa 2.1.9 and therefore do not need  custom handling of LocalDate/LocalDateTime properties in my RestControllers if i use an @RequestBody XXXEntity entity parameter.
But when injecting an OnjectMapper bean to my RestController and try to objectMapper.readValue(entityJson, entityClass) deserialisation fails on LocalDate properties.

How can i deserialize the way spring does (correctly) if the entity class is known upfront?

1.) Exception without custom configuration:
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `java.time.LocalDate` (no Creators, like default construct, exist): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('2019-10-29T00:00:00.000Z')

2.) When using an custom JSR310Module ObjecktMapper

java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2019-10-29T00:00:00.000Z' could not be parsed, unparsed text found at index 10

```java
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.json()
                .serializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
                .featuresToDisable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS) 
                .modules(new JSR310Module())
                .build();
```

```java
Same error with custom DateFormat:
  SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
        objectMapper.setDateFormat(df);
```

I tried registering the LocalDateTime Deserializer for LocalDate das well:

```java
 Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.json()
    .deserializerByType(LocalDate.class, LocalDateTimeDeserializer.INSTANCE)
```

Result gets better... so paring fails where i hit the UTC timezon:
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2019-10-29T00:00:00.000Z' could not be parsed, unparsed text found at index 23

**This is how my Controller looks like:**

```java
    @Autowired
    public AdminRestController(EntityService entityService, ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        this.entityService = entityService;
        this.objectMapper = objectMapper;
    }

...

    @Transactional
    @PostMapping(value = "/entities/{entityName}")
    public List<T> createEntity(@PathVariable String entityName, @RequestBody String entityJson) {
        T newEntity = constructEntity(entityName, entityJson);
        entityService.create(newEntity);
        ...
    }
...
    private T constructEntity(String entityName, String entityJson) {
        Class<T> entityClass;
        try {
            entityClass = findClassByName(entityName);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Entity " + entityName + " unknwon.");
        }
        try {
            T entity = objectMapper.readValue(entityJson, entityClass);
            return entity;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Unable to construct entity  " + entityName + " from provided data.", e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried to register `JavaTimeModule` from [jackson-modules-java8](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8). `JSR310Module` is obsolete.

Comment: @MichałZiober: good point, i had a look into the time module and indead there is some special handling there in place that goes into the right direction.

strangely though when detecting timezone data in the input string LocalDateDeserializer uses 
LocalDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.parse(string), ZoneOffset.UTC) which incorrectly
reads e.g. '2019-11-26T23:00' as  2019-11-26... (because UTC offset is defined as 0-second)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may consider it just as hacky. My version of the logic would be:

```
    if (string.isEmpty()) {
        return null;
    }
    if (string.endsWith("Z")) {
        return Instant.parse(string).atZone(ZONE_SWISS).toLocalDate();
    }
    return LocalDate.parse(string, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME);
```

I have avoided the modification of the string and the conversion from `LocalDateTime`to `LocalDate`. Also since the `Z` can only come last in the string, my version gives preciser validation. Finally as a matter of taste I like the `String.isEmpty` method.

Comment: your points are valid. My code snipped was not that well thought. ;)
isEmpty() and using different parse=patterns is prefferable.
Though it does not solve the ability to parse a date out of an all-zero-time DateTime string. So it does not solve my problem.

Comment: or at least i still have the issue that the wrong date is parsed. so when when my time is utc+1 this results an day before cause 0:00 gets 23:00 and therefore the day before the chosen date.

Comment: With the atZone() part this should work. I'll accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I have a "solution" for my problem... but it feals hacky...

I tracked down my problem to one root source:
 - my clients always sends timezoned-utc-strings as dates e.g. '2019-10-29T00:00:00.000Z' (including time information as well) instead of "real" date-strings.
 - Strangely springboot by default (at least with spring-boot-starter-web, etc) handles this correctly if such a strings hits an LocalDate attribute when serializeing.
 - If i try to manually rebuild this behaviour with jacksons ObjectMapper i am not able to solve both problems at the same time and hit either an pasre error on the time or  the timezone information.

What helps e.g. is annotating my Pojo with an Custom deserializer:

```java
    @JsonDeserialize(using = LocalDateTimeStringToLocalDateDeserializer.class)
    private LocalDate validFrom;
```

```java
/*
 * Copyright 2013 FasterXML.com
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may
 * not use this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain
 * a copy of the License at
 *
 *     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the license for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the license.
 */

package ch.acrevison.tpl.findata.util.serializing;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonDeserializer;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

/**
 * Deserializer for Java 8 temporals
 * 1.) parses string as LocalDateTime if it is longer as an expected iso date.
 * 1.a ) if utc timezone marker is contained>
 */
public class LocalDateTimeStringToLocalDateDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<LocalDate> implements java.io.Serializable {

    private static ZoneId ZONE_SWISS = ZoneId.of("Europe/Zurich");

    @Override
    public LocalDate deserialize(JsonParser parser, DeserializationContext context) throws IOException {

        String string = parser.getText().trim();
        if (string.length() == 0) {
            return null;
        }

        if (string.endsWith("Z")) {
            ZonedDateTime utcZonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.parse(string);
            ZonedDateTime localDateTime = utcZonedDateTime.withZoneSameInstant(ZONE_SWISS);
            return localDateTime.toLocalDate();
        } else if (string.length() > 10) {
            return LocalDate.parse(string, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME);
        } else {
            return LocalDate.parse(string);
        }
    }
}
```

No better ideas around?

Comment: Educate your clients better?

Comment: well. unfortunally it seams quite "normal" for a client to send all-zero-timestamps for representing a date.  See e.g. angulars material uimplementation which uses timestamps for its datepicker etc.

So "educate your client"would mean changeing the world instead of "implementing an api that works within this world...

Comment: i updated my answer to work around the problem that an string like '2019-11-25T23:00:00.000Z'wrongly gets deserialized as 25 instead of 26 by first parsing as utc, converting manually to the local timezone to extract the correct LocalDate....

Still hacky though,

Comment: I updated my answer accordingly. If it does the work, I don’t consider it too hacky, no matter if you take your own code or mine.

Comment: Looks good for me and should work. I'll accept your answer even if now both our answers are very similar because the improvements you suggested are a bit more elegant.